# Finding the Joint Distribution of Two Normally Distributed Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution, bivariate-distributions

**Question:** Suppose $X_1$, $X_2$ and $X_3$ are *independent* random variables such that $X_1 \sim N(0,1)$, $X_2 \sim N(1,4)$ and $X_3 \sim N(-1,2)$. Let $Y_1=X_1+X_3$ and $Y_2=X_1+X_2-2X_3$. Give the joint distribution of $Y_1$ and $Y_2$.

**My attempt:** So far I have calculated that $Y_1 \sim N(-1, 3)$ and $Y_2 \sim N(3, 13)$ by use of the fact the independence of the $X_i$ implies that any linear combination of them is also a normally distributed random variable. However, I am unsure how to find their joint distribution.

**Theory:** Considering the transformation $Z=\mu+BX$ where:

- B is some $m \times n$ matrix
- $X$ is a vector of iid standard normal variables
- $Z$ has expectation vector $\mu$ and covariance matrix $\Sigma = BB^T$

Then we have $Z \sim N(\mu, \Sigma)$.

**Application of theory:** I presume in my case I would let $Y$ denote the column vector $[Y_1, Y_2]^T$. Then, from my above working, the expectation vector would be $\mu = [-1, 3]^T$. However, I am not sure how to go from here to determine what $X$ would be or how to calculate the covariance matrix $\Sigma$.

Comment: By considering $\varphi$ from vector $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ to vector (let's say) $(X_1+X_3,X_1+X_2-2X_3,X_3) =: (Y_1,Y_2,Y_3)$ which is a linear transformation, you can be sure that it is a gaussian vector, too, so $(Y_1,Y_2)$ as a subvector of gaussian vector will be gaussian. Now just calculate $\mathbb E[(Y_1,Y_2)] = \mathbb E[(X_1 + X_3 , X_1 +X_2 - 2X_3)] = (-1,3)$ and due to independence of $X_1,X_2,X_3$ we have $Var(Y_1) = Var(X_1)+Var(X_3) =3, Var(Y_2) = Var(X_1) + Var(X_2) + 4Var(X_3) = 13$ and for covariance: $Cov(Y_1,Y_2) = Var(X_1) - 2 Var(X_3) = -3$

Comment: If $\boldsymbol X \sim \mathcal N(\boldsymbol \mu, \Sigma)$, then $A \boldsymbol X \sim \mathcal N(A \boldsymbol \mu, A \Sigma A^t)$. Now let
$$A = \begin {pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & -2 \end {pmatrix}.$$